# Websockets connection fails on Pivotal Cloud but works on localhost

Tags: stomp, spring-websocket, cloud-foundry, sockjs

I have a Java Spring Boot based web service called cde-service and an Angular 5 based front end called abc-app.

abc-app uses a websocket connection to send logging data to cde-service that in turn does something with the client side log data.

I have tested the applications on localhost and they work as expected.

However when I deploy cde-service onto Pivotal Cloud Foundry, the websocket connection fails with 403 Forbidden. I have done the changes to allow CORS.

Any pointers as to why this is happening would be really helpful.

**cde-service :**

```js
// Snippet from the Websocket Configuration. 

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
  registry.addEndpoint("/websocketConnection").setAllowedOrigins("*").withSockJS();
}


@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {

  registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/queue");
  registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}



// Snippet from the Controller.

@MessageMapping("/logs")
public void handleLogs(LogModel logModel) {
  logService.logHandler(logModel);
}
```

**abc-app :**

```js
var sock = new SockJS("http://host_name/websocketConnection");
var stomp = Stomp.over(sock);

stomp.connect('guest', 'guest', function(frame) {
  console.log('----    Established Connection  ----');
});

stomp.send("/app/logs", {},
  JSON.stringify({
    'logData': 'Some Data'
  }));
```

Comment: Are you trying to pull the event logs from PCF for your app?

Comment: I think you should take a look at the [loggregator architecture](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-2/loggregator/architecture.html) for Pivotal Cloud Foundry.

Comment: Another worthwhile read - https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/firehose-to-syslog

Comment: @K.AJ Logging is just one of the things I intend to use web sockets for.

Comment: PCF websockets are only exposed through loggergator framework. You will have to build an app called `nozzle` and deploy it. Look at the community `firehose-to-syslog` nozzle link I pasted above.

Comment: @K.AJ - That's not correct.  You're talking about using WebSockets against Loggregator which is certainly something you can do, but it's by no means the only thing you can do with WebSockets on Cloud Foundry.  *Any* app that runs on CF can use WebSockets and the app can use it for whatever purpose the app sees fit.    That app does *not* need to create a nozzle or anything else.  Any standard WebSocket client, like the one found in a browser, should work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However when I deploy cde-service onto Pivotal Cloud Foundry, the websocket connection fails with 403 Forbidden. I have done the changes to allow CORS.

Cloud Foundry does not add any stipulations for using WebSockets in your app.  The standard browser client should work fine.  In this case, your client app is attempting to connect to your server app and your server app is returning a 403.  The only way you can figure out why is to debug your server app and see why it's saying that the WebSocket connection is forbidden.

The platform would not be generating the 403.

To me CORS is the most likely culprit, but there's by no means enough information here for me to make that determination and it could be other things as well.  Turn up the log levels in your app and see what's happening.  Also, try testing locally but using multiple domains so that you actually have to deal with CORS.

The only other thing to watch out for here, is that some installations of Cloud Foundry require your WebSocket connections to go over a different port.  This is not a limitation of Cloud Foundry, but of the load balancer used by your platform operator.  In some cases, like when running on AWS, the load balancers (ELB, *cough*) do not support having HTTP, HTTPS and WebSockets traffic all over the same port.  To work around this load balancer limitation, operators will have separate ports for each protocol, i.e. HTTP -> 80, HTTPS 443, WSS 4443.  Check with your platform operator to see how your environment was deployed.

Comment: It was a CORS issue, you were right. My connections were routing through another service in PCF which gave me a "The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values" initially because the CORS filter was present in both the services. Then I removed the CORS filter from cde-service, I started getting "403 Forbidden". Once I added the CORS filter again on cde-service and tried to connect to cde-service using a direct url, the connection was successful.